# How many nodes are there of each degree?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graph-theory

Q:A graph has 12 edges and 6 nodes, each of which has degree of 2 or 5. How many nodes are there of each degree?

let m = the amount of edges, then $$  2m = \sum_{v\in V} deg(V) $$

from here we can see that the right side equation will = 2(12) = 24

the only way we can get 24 from 6 nodes of either degree 5 or 2 is:

4 nodes of degree 5 and 2 nodes of degree 2

am I correct in my work?

Comment: It is a matter of solving a system linear of equations: $2x + 5y = 24$ and $x + y = 6$